# Compare a value with multiple values Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to power bi and stuck while comparing values. Below is the ask.

I need to compare the value in Depart Column with the value in Depart Type Column with below given rules

[image]

[image]

IF values mismatch i need to report it as yes and if not with no as depicted. any leads via DAX or M-query will be helpful.

Regards

Mahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a column that calculates the types correctly like this:

```
Type = SWITCH(TRUE(),
           SEARCH("Red",     Table1[Depart], 1, 0) > 0, "Red",
           SEARCH("Green",   Table1[Depart], 1, 0) > 0, "Green",
           SEARCH("High",    Table1[Depart], 1, 0) > 0, "StairwayIN",
           SEARCH("Low",     Table1[Depart], 1, 0) > 0, "StairwayOUT",
           SEARCH("Virtual", Table1[Depart], 1, 0) > 0, "Virtual",
           BLANK()
       )
```

From there you just need to test if `[Type] = [Depart Type]`.

---

Here are a couple of relevant references you may find useful:

[DAX String Comparison](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-string-comparison/)

[Explanation of `SWITCH(TRUE(), ...)`](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/)